# Angular language service doesn't work in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Angular Version

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.6
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.6
@angular/cli                      7.3.6
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.6
@schematics/angular               7.3.6
@schematics/update                0.13.6
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.2.4
webpack                           4.29.0
```

Angular Language Service Version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFtvn.png)

This is the official language service introduction link. https://angular.io/guide/language-service

I try to get the variable defined in my component but get no intellisence. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

vscode [menu]-> [help] -> [Toggle Developer Tools];

say vscode version need ^1.3.0;

so i upgrade my vscode